# UITapGestureRecognizer on multiple UIView (scrollview subviews)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have set a scrollview and a bench of `UIView` (scrollview subviews) with gestures on them:

```
  for (id element in array) {

        CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] init];
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(x, 16, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollContentSizeWidth, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(selectView:)];
        [self.view setTag:[[element valueForKey:@"Id"] integerValue]];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
        scrollContentSizeWidth +=110;
        x += 110;
    }
```

The called method when a view is touched:

```
-(void)selectView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    NSLog(@"id : %i",recognizer.view.tag);//always last assigned value in the loop above

}
```

So how to fix that? `UITapGestureRecognizer` seems to be affected to the last view only.

Comment: [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; add on your CustomView not on the main view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this line

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

with this

```
 [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Comment: I definitely need some coffee

Comment: this is just because of the naming conversion. you should give proper name of any object..